# C - Getting malloc errors only in Eclipse Debugger

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, malloc

so, i had to create a function that receives an unsigned char*, turns it to char*, and returns the result.

```
char *getFileName(unsigned char *nombreArchivo){
int i = 0;
char *nombre;
while(nombreArchivo[i] != '\0' && i <= 17){

    i++;
}

size_t tamanio = i + 1;
nombre = malloc(tamanio); // THE FUNCTION DIES HERE
memcpy(nombre, nombreArchivo, tamanio);

return nombre;
```

}

im having several issues with this:

1) the function is being called inside a for(), but it does not crash at the beginning. Actually, the loop iterates several times before crashing.

2) this crash ONLY happens when i run the code on the eclipse debugger. If i run it on a linux terminal, it will work properly, without issues.

3) the crash happens most of the time at the same amount of loops. My first guess was that the problem was related with the available memory for the debugger. I increased the memory, but it keeps crashing at the same amount of loops.

Any clues?

EDIT: forgot to mention, but each time the function is called again, the variable nombre still has the return value from the previous iteration. thing is, if i try to do a free() of the variable where i store the return value of getFileName(), the program crashes right there too.

Here is the code of the calling function:

```
char *osada_readdir(char *unaRuta){

char *contenido = string_new();
char *nombreArchivo = string_new();
char *separador = ";";
int parentBlock = buscarArchivo(unaRuta);
int i;

if(parentBlock == 999999){
    printf("there is no such directory/subdirectory\n");
    exit(0);
}

for (i = 0; i <= 2048; i++){

        if(miDisco.tablaDeArchivos[i].parent_directory == parentBlock){
            nombreArchivo = getFileName(miDisco.tablaDeArchivos[i].fname); // I verified that the .fname field is being read properly
            if(strlen(nombreArchivo) > 0){
                contenido = concat(contenido, nombreArchivo);

                contenido = concat(contenido, separador);

            //
            }
        }
    }


   //free(nombreArchivo); // if i dont comment this, program crashes aswell.
   return contenido;

   }
```

Comment: Maybe the nombre string isn't properly terminated with a NUL character? That'd happen if nombreArchivo is too long. If nombre is used outside the getFileName(), maybe that causes the problem you see?

Comment: This seemed like a probable reason. I just tested it by adding a '\0' at the nombre variable before returning it, but the crash is still there. Not sure if i followed your reasoning 100% though.

Comment: @BjornA. by the way, i forgot to mention that, each time the function is called again, the variable "nombre" still has the return value from the previous iteration. Maybe this is related? gonna edit the post just in case

Comment: Where does `nombreArchivo` come from?

Comment: @eddiem going to add the calling function for clarification.

Comment: Code is having trouble yet code does not check the result of `malloc()`.  Hmmm, at minimum, check that result `assert(nombre);`.

Comment: cheking. Edited

Comment: Is the data pointed to by `contenido` initialized?

Comment: `char *nombreArchivo = string_new(); ...  nombreArchivo = getFileName(...`.  looks odds.  why assign `nombreArchivo` twice in a row?

Comment: The issue is most likely caused by failing to NULL-terminate the memory you're `malloc()`ing.  Make sure you set `nombre[tamanio]` to `\x00` before returning.

Comment: @chux it is; string_new() returns a pointer to an empty string